# Best TCP/ NIC settings for QuickFix/.Net

Tags: c#, performance, tcp, quickfix, quickfixn

I am receiving data via QuickFix/Net from several very active market data providers.

I see occasional consumption issues (latencies between dumpcap log and FIX tag 52).

My server is very busy, and I would to know if there are recommendations for setting TCP and/or adapter that would give QuickFix/Net the best performance.

Comment: If you need continuous microsecond response times, perhaps don't use a managed environment such as .NET, which can arbitrarily freeze your application  to collect garbage. Why do you think the problem is in the TCP layer?

Comment: Stuck with c#. I don't know where it is and I am trying to eliminate things starting at where the message is received.

Comment: You could use tcp or udp multicast with supported hardware

Comment: If your server hardware comes from HP then have a chat with your HP partner. They provide white papers on how to configure the BIOS/UEFI for high frequency trading and low latency.